# Android Gradle Why do we need "allprojects"?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I faced a problem when I tried to add Gson to my existing Android gradle project.

The exception was something like this

> " failed to resolve:com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1"

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
.
.
```

After some searching and trial and error I found that you need to add the following to fix the issue:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Why to do we need to reference the jcenter two times and  why was the "allprojects" important to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> After some searching and trail and error i found that you need to add the following to fix the issue

Only if you have a traditional Android Studio project, where you have the application divided into modules (e.g., `app/`). What is really required is for the module to know where to pull dependencies from.

> Why to do we need to reference the jcenter two times

The `repositories` closure in your `buildscript` closure says "these are the artifact repositories from which to pull Gradle plugins and other `dependencies` listed for the `buildscript` closure itself".

The `repositories` closure that you have in `allprojects` closure says "these are the artifact repositories from which to pull your own application `dependencies`".

In a traditional Android Studio project, the `allprojects` closure goes in the `build.gradle` file that is in the project root directory. `allprojects` says "everything in this closure, please apply to the Gradle configuration for all of the modules in this project, such as that `app/` module over there".

Now, your `build.gradle` snippet in your question hints that perhaps you do *not* have a traditional Android Studio project, but instead have one where you do not have an `app/` module and you have only one `build.gradle` file. In that case, `allprojects` itself is not necessary (as there are no modules), but you still need to specify what the `repositories` are.

For example, here is a `build.gradle` file from [a module-less project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:wakeful:1.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            targetSdkVersion 17
        }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Here, in addition to a `repositories` closure inside `buildscript` (to define where the plugins come from), I have a top-level `repositories` closure, to define where the top-level `dependencies` come from.

Answer (score 0):

They are just different repositories where the libraries are stored. GSON is obviously in the JCentral and others are using the Maven Ventral.

From reading up on JCenter, it is the repository behind Bintray, from the company JFrog (who I've come across before, and I guess that's where the 'J' comes from). According to the Bintray blog, Bintray is a superset of Maven Central.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. @CommonsWare's answer is correct.